# Are these encoded codes?

Tags: java, applet, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the jsr keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312426/what-does-the-jsr-keyword-mean)

i used a decompiler to decompile a .class file it seems that it decompiled everything except some code at the bottom are very strange and since im new to java im not sure what they mean:

```
  static
  {
    String[] tmp5_2 = new String[6];
    jsr 50;
    tmp5_2[0] = "pH@JeAE";
    String[] tmp13_5 = tmp5_2;
    jsr 42;
    tmp13_5[1] = "lRMMoF";
    String[] tmp21_13 = tmp13_5;
    jsr 34;
    tmp21_13[2] = "KHUT;\f\19VSv\rRHJkBJH@dL\18OAu";
    String[] tmp29_21 = tmp21_13;
    jsr 26;
    tmp29_21[3] = "\18\14\22\n1\r\f\15\21";
    String[] tmp37_29 = tmp29_21;
    jsr 18;
    tmp37_29[4] = "wTD\4OJRKEWJXDK@SLMAu\3UR\4NMPHJd\r";
    String[] tmp45_37 = tmp37_29;
    jsr 10;
    tmp45_37[5] = "KHUT;\f\19\16\226\r\f\15\20/\18\19RP`WIR";
    z = tmp45_37;
    break label68:
    label68: localObject = returnAddress;
  }
```

see the code after `tmp5_2[0]` for example, what do they mean?

Comment: Why are you decompiling? Have a word with the author instead. There's almost no programming reason to be decompiling code.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from a quick glance, and I could be totally wrong, it looks like code that has been obfuscated by an obfuscation tool as to prevent what you are trying to do (reverse engineering)

Comment: Also, check the license agreement that you signed / clicked-through to get the software.  I would be very surprised if it doesn't explicitly forbid reverse engineering!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code you post is not valid Java code.

The bytecode you de-compiled to get this was most likely obfuscated by some obfuscator that also obfuscates String constants (the only obfuscater I use occasionally is [ZKM](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/) and that does something similar).

Note this code in your sample:

```
jsr 50;
```

That's not a valid Java statement and is included by the decompiler to tell you that there was a bytecode instruction that it couldn't de-compile into a valid Java source statement.

`jsr` is effectively a `gosub` (i.e. it pushes the return address on the stack and invokes the bytecode at the specified offset, it's usually used to implement `finally`-blocks), so this code is probably used to jump to some String "decryption" subroutine (I put decryption in quotes because it most likely isn't a strongly typographic decryption at work here).

Answer (score 0):

These are most likely encrypted strings for use within the application. The applet should include some sort of decryption routine for them or it wouldn't be able to use them. This looks to me like a poorly decompiled or obfuscated initialization code for some field in the class called `z` (an array of String).

As far as Java is concerned, these are just regular string constants. There is no special significance to them whatsoever.

Comment: is there anyway to decrypt those strings, if so, how?

Comment: You can't tell how to decrypt them unless you know how they were encrypted. What were you decompiling anyways?

Comment: The short answer is: yes. The longer answer is: The applet must decrypt these strings to be able to work (unless they are encryption *keys*, which is quite possible). Therefore, the applet code must contain the decryption routine and probably also the key if there is such a thing with the algorithm they are using.