# Using java applet to send request with the client ip

Tags: java, curl, applet

i need to send a request to a website when a user submits their url, i tried using curl but it uses server ip which i dont want i have seen a website that is doing a similar job by using applet, users need to open a popup which contains the applet after they leave it open allow it to run it uses a port and then uses the localhost ip like so 127.0.0.1:64653 to send request and basicly curl by the user ip. i decompiled the applet the website was using and they were using java.net.ServerSocket and some other java code but i do not know anything about java. I would to know how this can be done.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean "when a user submits their url"? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: when users submit their url it gets some of the specified content, by curl, i did that by curl but it uses server ip which i dont want to i want it to use the user ip, there is a site which is doing the exact thing, by they did it using java applet which uses the user ip using the method i explained above, i would like to know how its done. please help me!

Comment: This is a website about programming questions - not about how to hack other people's programmes, which is how you're coming across in this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135864/are-these-encoded-codes

Answer (score 1):

I think you are really confused.

1. a user does not have a URL.
2. there is a IP address that
   represents the browser end of the
   connection to the web server he/she
   is connected to (actually, there
   could be more than one) but this
   does not allow something else to
   establish a connection to the
   browser.  So it is not a URL.
3. the IP address + port number
   that the browser has are transient.
   In 2 minutes time, the very same
   IP/port could denote a different
   user, possibly even on a different
   machine.
4. 127.0.0.1 is a "special" IP
   address that says "this machine". 
   It cannot be used for communication
   with another machine.
5. notwithstanding all of the
   above, web browsers do not accept
   incoming HTTP connections from web
   servers or anything else.  The HTTP
   protocol (which is what the web
   works on) distinguishes between the
   roles of "client" and "server", and
   specifies that a client connects to
   a server *and not the other way
   round*.  A web browser is always an
   HTTP client, by convention and also
   for security reasons.

So when you say ...

> i need to send a request to a website when a user submits their url

... it simply does not make any sense.  Please explain what you are tying to achieve ... not how you are trying to achieve it ... and we might be able to help.